# Parameter mapping for a table name

Tags: ssis

I have a delete statement. Delete from <table name>. I want to make table name dynamic by passing parameter. how can I do this? I have used like delete from ?, but giving other must declared the table variable.

Comment: DELETE pv  FROM tablename pv wher condition. i want the tablename to ba passed by parameter. how can I?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the parameter placeholder (?) in the FROM clause.
However you can create a Variable(1) called for example "SQL Query" and define a Expression (2):
[image]

The Expression should look like this.
[image]

In the Execute SQL Task Editor you can choose Variable under SQLSourceType and under SourceVariable you can choose "SQL Query"